# sql server datetime hourly interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "logintracking" and fields are "attemptresult" and "attemptdate".

```
attemptdate             attemptresult
2007-12-18 14:33:24.000 LOGOUT
2007-12-18 14:33:38.000 SUCCESS
2007-12-18 14:35:36.000 LOGOUT
2007-12-18 14:46:50.000 SUCCESS
2007-12-18 16:52:48.000 TIMEOUT
2007-12-18 16:57:33.000 SUCCESS
2007-12-18 18:49:49.000 TIMEOUT
2008-01-10 13:02:32.000 SUCCESS
```

and so on

i want the result as:

```
DATE                    COUNT(login)
2007-12-18 14:00:00.000 1
2007-12-18 15:00:00.000 0
2007-12-18 16:00:00.000 0
2007-12-18 17:00:00.000 0
2007-12-18 18:00:00.000 0   
2007-12-18 19:00:00.000 0
2007-12-18 20:00:00.000 0
2008-01-10 01:00:00.000 0
```

i.e. each hour starting with the minimum attemptdate till the maximum attemptdate
and correspondingly count of login and logout at particular time.
please help

Comment: Can you explain how you calculated the `Login` count in your output ?? The sample data and expected output don't make sense.

Comment: The login calculation appears to be SUCCESS followed by a LOGOUT, however that then begs the question - if there's any relationship between the login (success) and logouts? or whether you just want to know whether a success is directly followed by a logout within the same interval

Comment: SELECT dateadd(hour,DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, attemptdate),0) as a ,
COUNT(attemptresult) as LOGIN
    FROM logintracking
    WHERE attemptresult='LOGIN'
     group by  dateadd(hour,DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, attemptdate),0)

Comment: I did login count  as in above query. same for logout.

Comment: Then i used join and sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how to compute for the Login count, here is what I came up:

The idea is to generate hourly intervals of all dates in `LoginTracking`. Then `LEFT JOIN` that into the `LoginTracking` to achieve the result:

```
CREATE TABLE LoginTracking(
    AttemptDate     DATETIME,
    AttemptResult   VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO LoginTracking VALUES
('2007-12-18 14:33:24.000', 'LOGOUT'),
('2007-12-18 14:33:38.000', 'SUCCESS'),
('2007-12-18 14:35:36.000', 'LOGOUT'),
('2007-12-18 14:46:50.000', 'SUCCESS'),
('2007-12-18 16:52:48.000', 'TIMEOUT'),
('2007-12-18 16:57:33.000', 'SUCCESS'),
('2007-12-18 18:49:49.000', 'TIMEOUT'),
('2008-01-10 13:02:32.000', 'SUCCESS');

;WITH CteCross AS(
    SELECT
        lt.AttemptDate,
        N = x.N - 1
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            CAST(AttemptDate AS DATE) AS AttemptDate
        FROM LoginTracking
    )lt
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6  UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL SELECT 9  UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL
        SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL
        SELECT 21 UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23 UNION ALL SELECT 24 
    )x(N)
)
SELECT 
    AttemptDate = DATEADD(HOUR, cc.N, CAST(cc.AttemptDate AS DATETIME)),
    LoginCount = SUM(CASE WHEN lt.AttemptResult = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM CteCross cc
LEFT JOIN LoginTracking lt
    ON CAST(lt.AttemptDate AS DATE) = cc.AttemptDate
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, lt.AttemptDate) = cc.N
GROUP BY cc.AttemptDate, cc.N
ORDER BY AttemptDate


DROP TABLE LoginTracking
```

Comment: can you please explain N = x.N - 1?

Comment: please explain select used inside cross join

Comment: The `SELECT` inside the `CROSS JOIN` generate rows from 1 to 24. I use `N - 1` since the `HOUR` part of `DATETIME` ranges from 0 to 23.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt Result is not so clear.you should explain why on 14th logincount=1 and why on 16th it is 0.

Try this,

```
DECLARE  @LoginTracking TABLE(
    AttemptDate     DATETIME,
    AttemptResult   VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @LoginTracking VALUES
('2007-12-18 14:33:24.000', 'LOGOUT'),
('2007-12-18 14:33:38.000', 'SUCCESS'),
('2007-12-18 14:35:36.000', 'LOGOUT'),
('2007-12-18 14:46:50.000', 'SUCCESS'),
('2007-12-18 16:52:48.000', 'TIMEOUT'),
('2007-12-18 16:57:33.000', 'SUCCESS'),
('2007-12-18 18:49:49.000', 'TIMEOUT'),
('2008-01-10 13:02:32.000', 'SUCCESS');

DECLARE @MinDate DateTime=
(SELECT DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour, 0,min(AttemptDate)), 0) FROM @LoginTracking)
DECLARE @MaxDate DateTime=
(SELECT DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour, 0,max(AttemptDate)), 0) FROM @LoginTracking)



;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT @MinDate [DATE]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(hour, 1, [date])
    FROM cte
    WHERE [date] < @MaxDate
    )
SELECT [DATE]
    ,isnull((
            SELECT TOP 1 1
            FROM @LoginTracking lt
            WHERE DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, AttemptDate), 0) = [Date]
                AND (
                    EXISTS (
                        SELECT AttemptResult
                        FROM @LoginTracking lt
                        WHERE DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, AttemptDate), 0) = [Date]
                            AND lt.AttemptResult = 'LOGOUT'
                        )
                    AND EXISTS (
                        SELECT AttemptResult
                        FROM @LoginTracking lt
                        WHERE DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, AttemptDate), 0) = [Date]
                            AND lt.AttemptResult = 'SUCCESS'
                        )
                    )
            ), 0)
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: for understanding purpose,you can comment the whole select after CTE.
and just use select * from CTE.I hv use recursive CTE to generate Date range between min date and max date.Thatsy there are 522 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
case  
when TAB_1.a is NULL then TAB_2.a 
else TAB_1.a
END
"ATTEMPT DATE",
case 
when TAB_1.LOGIN  IS NULL  then 0
else TAB_1.LOGIN
END
"LOGIN",
case 
when TAB_2.LOGOUT  IS NULL  then 0
else TAB_2.LOGOUT
END
"LOGOUT"

FROM  
    (SELECT dateadd(hour,DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, attemptdate),0) as a ,
COUNT(attemptresult) as LOGIN
    FROM logintracking
    WHERE attemptresult='LOGIN'
     group by  dateadd(hour,DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, attemptdate),0)
     ) AS TAB_1
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT dateadd(hour,DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, attemptdate),0) as a,
COUNT(attemptresult) as LOGOUT
    FROM logintracking
    WHERE attemptresult='LOGOUT' 
     group by  dateadd(hour,DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, attemptdate),0) ) AS TAB_2
on TAB_1.a=TAB_2.a order by TAB_1.a
```

I used this to show all the login and logout corresponding to attempt date.
but i want to show where my login and logout both will be '0'. and attempdate is hourly shown